# Webpack doesn´t bundle jquery

Tags: jquery, webpack

I created a web application in VS2017 (ASP.NET MVC Core, .NET 4.6)
and installed web pack extension for visual studio

webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict"
{
    // Required to form a complete output path
    let path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    // Plugin for cleaning up the output folder (bundle) before creating a new one
    const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

    // Path to the output folder
    const bundleFolder = "wwwroot/bundle/";

    module.exports = {
        // Application entry point
        entry: "./app/main.ts",

        // Output file
        output: {
            filename: 'script.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, bundleFolder)
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: "ts-loader"
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
            root: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')

            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder]),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery",
                'window.$': 'jquery',
            })

        ],
        // Include the generation of debugging information within the output file
        // (Required for debugging client scripts)
        devtool: "inline-source-map"
    };
}
```

jquery resides in **./node_modules**

I expected to see a bundled jquery code in **script.js** but it isn't there

Comment: What does your main.ts file look like? Just to be sure ... are you using jQuery in there somewhere?

Comment: @Peter in my main.ts I don't have a jquery code. class Test {
    getMessage() {
        return "hellos";
    }
}
Is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, I don't believe webpack will bundle it unless you actually use it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe webpack will bundle it unless you're actually using it somewhere. Try adding something like this to your entry point (or a module that it imports):

```
console.log('jquery version:', jQuery.fn.jquery);
```

That should get webpack to add it to your bundle.